# nuproj.props file is missing

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

I have a library that I can successfully build locally and on another computer.  However, when I try to do the build at VSTS online, I get

> classes.csproj(152,5): Error : This project references NuGet
>   package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package
>   Restore to download them. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is
>   ....\classes\packages\NuProj.0.11.30\build\NuProj.props

I have tried multiple times to check the git repository but comparison shows that the VSTS version is the same.

What am I missing?  Do I need to delete this VSTS project and simply reload?  Hoping not.

Comment: Did you add NuGet restore task before VS Build task? And can you show the whole build logs here?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you need to do a manual nuget restore before building your project. Visual studio can take care of this automatically. But from the command line, msbuild is not running visual studio.

Thus do something like

`nuget restore c:\my\path\to\my\project.sln`